# How to truncate the title of a tabbarcontroller item

Tags: ios

I'm creating tabbaritems dynamically, and sometimes the title of the item exceeds the item's space and it take the space of the next tabbaritem.

Somebody knows how to prevent it? How to truncate the name?

Sorry, but I can't post photos yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no easy way to do it.

You can truncate NSString to some defined width( in ex. "TestBarTitle"->"TestB.." ) before setting it as a title:

```
- (NSString*)stringByTruncatingStringWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode {
    NSMutableString *resultString = [[self mutableCopy] autorelease];
    NSRange range = {resultString.length-1, 1};

    while ([resultString sizeWithFont:font forWidth:FLT_MAX lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode].width > width) {
        // delete the last character
        [resultString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
        range.location--;
        // replace the last but one character with an ellipsis
        [resultString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:truncateReplacementString];
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

Or you can manually implement UITabBar ( UIImageView + UIButtons and UILabels ), so you will have 100% control of this UI element;

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Swift 4.2:

```
var resultString = title

var attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: resultString, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])

while attributedText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 15), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil).size.width > availableWidth {
    // delete last character
    resultString.removeLast(2)
    resultString.append(".")
    attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: resultString, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font])
}
```